# ScrollView takes away LinearLayout constraints

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to implement a ScrollView on a login screen over a LinearLayout, but the scroll view seems to mess up all the constraints on the LinearLayout.

Whats supposed to look like this

[image]

Instead looks like this when ScrollView is added

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_root_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bitmap_resource"
tools:context="dreamentries.dreamentries.LoginActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_center_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_edittxt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:hint="EMAIL"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_edittxt_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:hint="PASSWORD"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_center_login"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_login_earlyadopter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C0202020"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C0202020"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing in the ScrollView Attribute that prevents it from messing up the LinearLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to wrap the linearLayouts in a RelativeLayout then set the Scrollview to:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

The following will achieve the effect you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative_root_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bitmap_resource"
tools:context="dreamentries.dreamentries.LoginActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_center_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_edittxt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:hint="EMAIL"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_edittxt_pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.95"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:hint="PASSWORD"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_center_login"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_login_earlyadopter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C0202020"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#C0202020"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.095"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```